# Toggle hiding certain values in a dropdown box using a checkbox and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have a drop down box filled with options pulled from a database. Each of these options will have an active indicator value of either 'Y' or 'N'. I have a checkbox which will include all options or just the active ones.

I currently have the options pulling from the database perfectly. The for loop that inputs the options looks like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category_record); $i++) {
if($category_record[$i]->getActiveInd() == "Y")
              {
    echo '<option value="'.$category_record[$i]->getId().'" '.$checked.' >&nbsp;&nbsp; - '.$category_record[$i]->getTitle().'</option>';    
              }
else if($category_record[$i]->getActiveInd() == "N")
              {
    echo '<option id="inactive" value="'.$category_record[$i]->getId().'" '.$checked.' >&nbsp;&nbsp; - '.$category_record[$i]->getTitle().'</option>';    
              }
```

So if the value is an inactive value, that option will have an id of '#inactive'.

The checkbox is a simple one:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search_active" id="checkbox" />
```

The jQuery I have at the moment looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#inactive').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#inactive').hide();
    }
 });
});
```

This code does work, slightly, in that it will hide inactive values when the checkbox is unticked, however it will only hide the first value it comes across and not all of them.
I have inspected the elements and they all still definitely have the #inactive id but they won't hide. I have searched for an answer but haven't been able to find one, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use the same id multiple times on the same page! Use classes. Read: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more than one element you should use class `.active`, `.inactive` or create your own attribute such as state.

PHP:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category_record); $i++) {
if($category_record[$i]->getActiveInd() == "Y")
              {
    echo '<option value="'.$category_record[$i]->getId().'" '.$checked.' >&nbsp;&nbsp; - '.$category_record[$i]->getTitle().'</option>';    
              }
else if($category_record[$i]->getActiveInd() == "N")
              {
    echo '<option class="inactive" value="'.$category_record[$i]->getId().'" '.$checked.' >&nbsp;&nbsp; - '.$category_record[$i]->getTitle().'</option>';    
              }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.inactive').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.inactive').hide();
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you so much. I can't believe it was such a tiny thing. Not only have you given me the correct answer but also shown me a difference between class and id!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

use class 'inactive' for options in dropdown rather than id. and modify your js to show() and hide() using class.